# Set selected Kendo menu item with HtmlAttributes to hiddem form field

Tags: kendo-menu

i have a kendo menu that is bound to my form by the onclick event like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
    .Name("MenuCreate")
    .Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add().Text("<<").Action("Index", "BSfune");
        items.Add().Text("New").HtmlAttributes(new{onclick = "getElementById('FormCreate').submit()", @id = "New"});
        items.Add().Text("Edit").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "getElementById('FormCreate').submit()", @id = "Edit" });
    })
    .Events(e => e.Select("select"))
)
```

and in my form i have a hiden field called FormmMode

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "BSfune", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormCreate" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>@ViewBag.Title</legend> 
            <div>
               <div>
                   (My form code)
               </div>                    

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FormMode, new { @id = "FormMode"})
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />         
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>    
}
```

i want to set my field form (FormMode) with the selected menuitem text "New" or "Edit". 
I noticed that the onclick overrides the selected event. So.. It would be something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#New').on('click', function () {
        $("#FormMode").val($(this).text());
    });
});
function select(e) {
}
```

But this does not work..
On the controler side i have

```
 public ActionResult Create(CrBSfune p_BSfune)
    {
      (...)
       if (p_BSfune.FormMode == "New")
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

But my p_BSfune.FormMode is null.
Can you help?
Thanks.:)

Comment: Please.. Anyone? Web pages are not my area. It's probably a simple thing, but i do not see what i'm doing wrong?? Thank you.

Comment: Please.. Anyone? Tried the validation approach but it doesn't seem to be working either.. http://www.campusmvp.net/blog/validation-of-hidden-fields-at-the-client-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!! Catching the click event was the solution, the way to pass the value.. that was more trickie.. but after several attempts got it.:) did this and it works fine.:)

```
$('#New').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#FormCreate')[0].FormMode.value = e.target.innerText;
 $('#FormCreate').submit();});
```

Don't know if it is the best approach.. but it works.:)